# Take a div, remove some elements from print using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a print function in javascript that lifts a div element selected, replaces the html content and opens the print dialog so only the specific div is printed.

However inside that div there are some images and icons I need to also remove from the print dialog.

```
function printArticle(divId) {
        var originalHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printContent = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
        var imgs = document.getElementById(divId).getElementsByTagName('img');
        imgs[0].style.display = 'none';
        document.body.innerHTML = printContent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalHtml;
    }
```

Obviously the above code has no impact on the `printContent` that is used for the printable version, as its a string, so I'm unsure how to fix the logic here.

I've tried regex, but it would need to be very specific to the img tag and is not ideal in case that image were to change or something.

I would like the above solution to be usable on any element, as there is another div I would like to remove as well.

Comment: Is it not possible to use media queries in your CSS stylesheet to hide the imgs when printed?

Comment: @Rhumborl its possible, its just not something i'm familiar with so JS was the quick way I was thinking

Comment: Doing it through a print css query is definitely the easier option. For a JS option I'd recommend not doing it as a string, but instead creating a temporary div within JS, append the div to be printed to it, and then you can use the standard selectors and functions to remove the images.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely have to go the Javascript route rather than the CSS route, you could do something like the following:

```
function printArticle(divId) {
  const originalHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
  document.querySelectorAll('img')
    .forEach(img => img.remove())
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalHtml;
}
```

But note that assigning to `innerHTML` will destroy all existing element references in any other parts of your Javascript. It's a pretty bad option.

Another possibility is to open a *new* window with the appropriate images removed, and then print and close the *new* window, without changing anything in the original window.

Comment: yeh this might work if I use temp element because on printing completion it does not go back to original html

Comment: thank you - this helped, I will add my solution shortly

Answer (score 1):

```
    function printArticle(divId) {
        var originalHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printContent = document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => img.remove());
        printContent = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalHtml;
    }
```

Thanks to @CertainPerformance for the ideas to fix this.

Comment: Well, guess that means I did all this for nothing then; https://jsfiddle.net/at41pb3p/19/   -- The thing about what I did, though, is that my code is ready to be used in a non-destructive way... This is to say; you could use it without replacing the entire body, which could break bindings and such. + it also uses the actual after and before print bindings, which would probably be a lot more trustworthy.

Comment: ha thanks for your help - I will check it out and try it